# How to get twitter rate limit in v1.1

Tags: twitter

To get the twitter rate limit in v.1.1, I am doing :

```
$rate_limit = $connection->get('application/rate_limit_status', array('resource'=>'search'));
```

and `$rate_limit->resources->search` gives me:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [/search/tweets] => stdClass Object
        (
            [limit] => 180
            [remaining] => 177
            [reset] => 1389642298
        )

)
```

How to extract the remaining value from such an object? Trying to the twitter rate limit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done more research and realised I should use the curly bracket

```
$rate_limit->resources->search->{'/search/tweets'}->limit
```

Thanks